# Getting motherboard unique ID number thru vc++ programming

Tags: visual-c++

Is there any Unique ID or OEM (Original Equipment Manufacturer) number for Motherboard, if it is there , how can i get it thru vc++ programming? any hint or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

In this [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(VS.85).aspx), replace the `Win32_OperatingSystem` and `Name` in the code to the ones you are interested in (i.e. `Win32_BaseBoard` and `SerialNumber` for motherboard serial).

This WMI FAQ might be of interest: [Secrets of Windows Management Instrumentation: Troubleshooting and Tips](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/wmifaq.mspx)

Answer (score 2):

As @Mitch mentioned, you can use the WMI [`Win32_BaseBoard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394072(VS.85).aspx) class, `SerialNumber` property. Alternatively, for processor ID you can use the [`Win32_Processor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(VS.85).aspx) class, `ProcessorId` property.

Comment: Worth noting that on multiple processor machine Win32_Processor can return different results depending on the processor that is running