# Development of Station Licence in Borland C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, windows, licensing, hardware-interface, c++builder-6

I am using Borland C++ Builder 6 to design a Station Licence mechanism for a Windows application.

I have read that a Station Licence is bound to unique hardware information 
of the computer the application is running on.

What hardware information can I use?

How can I get this information using C++Builder 6?

Does C++Builder 6 have an encryption library?

Comment: I would start with a modern compiler / ide.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with @drescherjm. The C++ Builder 6 is more that 14 years old. You can get the starter edition of latest compiler for free from [Embarcadero's Website](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/starter).

> What hardware information could I use ??

The hardware info that you can use is the motherboard serial number wich can be obtained using WMI. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397591/getting-motherboard-unique-id-number-thru-vc-programming) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(VS.85).aspx).

> How can I get this information using "Borland C++ Builder 6" ??

Follow the links above. You have to use COM which **C++ Builder 6** was able to use.

> "Borland C++ Builder 6" has any encriptation library ?

No. But you can use OpenSSL. [Here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/OpenSSL) is the instruction for using it. You can also use the Windows [Cryptography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380256(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

Keep in mind that **C++ Builder 6**  will not run on any computer that has Vista or newer. Get the starter edition of latest compiler. It will create 32 bit windows app which sounds like is all you need.

Sam

Comment: Thank you for this sugestion. I am working on it.

Comment: If the answer works for you, could you please accept it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: C++Builder 6 *itself* might not run on Vista+ (you could run it in an XP virtual machine, though), but the executables that it produces run fine.